# Changing mysql date from an invalid date format

Tags: mysql, datetime

I had date data in excel as `dd-mm-yy H:i:s` format, I mistakenly imported it to mysql where default format was `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s` so all my date is wrong now, like `31-01-13 00:00:00` is became `2031-01-13 00:00:00` Now i can't import it again from excel so i need a mysql query to change the date within column.

Thanks
Farness

Comment: Best to use substring type functions most likely.  Are all the years 20**?

Comment: Sorry, Yes all have 20**... Minimum date is 2001-mm-dd and Maximum date is 2031-mm-dd (in mysql which is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating substrings from the date should work for all 2000s.  For 1900s, you would need an if.

First verify the dates with a SELECT:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
 '20', 
 substr(date, 9, 2), 
 '-',
 substr(date, 6, 2),
 '-',
 substr(date, 3, 2),
 ' ',
 TIME(date)
)
FROM table
```

Then you can update the columns in place:

```
UPDATE table SET date=CONCAT(
 '20', 
 substr(date, 9, 2), 
 '-',
 substr(date, 6, 2),
 '-',
 substr(date, 3, 2),
 ' ',
 TIME(date)
)
```

Comment: The query CONCAT (DAY(DATE),"-",MONTH(DATE), "-", YEAR(DATE), " 00:00:00") showing right date (i hope) is it ok... and how can i update the data

Comment: Normal date functions won't work because of the invalid format.

Comment: Convert the SELECT to an `UPDATE table SET date=CONCAT...`  Just  be sure the values output correctly first.